# RecyclerView: No adapter is attached; skipping layout - error inside of Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I have MainActivity that holds three tabs. In each tab I'm displaying data taken from SQLite db as list using RecyclerView.

When I first launch app the data is shown properly. After I return to previously opened tab the data is not there.

The problem started to appear after I have implemented following:

1. Check if adapter is null.
2. If yes, create adapter instance and fill it with data.
3. If no, just update the data inside of adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

This idea was working in other project where I had to do same with Activity. In this case I have fragment. I have just get to know that Fragment has different lifecycle behavior.

How I can solve this problem?

One of the tabs class:

```
public class AllTabView extends Fragment {

Context ourContext;

RecyclerView mList;
AllAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
TextView mEmptyText;

long movedItem, draggedItem;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mDays;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_content, container, false);

    mList = (RecyclerView) v1.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mEmptyText = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    ourContext = getContext();

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ourContext);
    mList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    mList.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);

    return v1;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDays();

    if (mDays.size() == 0) {
        mList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(adapter == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "adapter null");
            adapter = new AllAdapter(ourContext, mDays);
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG, "notify");
            adapter.updateData(mDays);
        }

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public void getDays() {
    DaysDatabase info = new DaysDatabase(ourContext);
    info.open();
    mDays = info.getData();
    info.close();
}

public void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new AllAdapter(ourContext, mDays);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

MainActivity that holds fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FragmentTabHost mFragmentTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mFragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mFragmentTabHost.setup(MainActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    String tag1 = "all";
    String tag2 = "since";
    String tag3 = "until";

    final View tabView1 = createTabView(MainActivity.this, "All");
    final View tabView2 = createTabView(MainActivity.this, "Since");
    final View tabView3 = createTabView(MainActivity.this, "Until");

    mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec(tag1).setIndicator(tabView1).setContent(new FragmentTabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag1) {
            return tabView1;
        }
    }), AllTabView.class, null);
    mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec(tag2).setIndicator(tabView2).setContent(new FragmentTabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag2) {
            return tabView2;
        }
    }), SinceTabView.class, null);
    mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec(tag3).setIndicator(tabView3).setContent(new FragmentTabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag1) {
            return tabView3;
        }
    }), UntilTabView.class, null);

    mFragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Try setting a log in `getDays()` method for checking whether mDays size (after being set) is 0. So you (and we) can know whether the problem is in that method or in adapter `updateData` method. And add adapter code to answer too

Comment: Please post out your activity code in which you are handling fragments.

Comment: As I understood, When I move to other tab active tab is calling `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroyView`. Therefore, we are losing the state of recyclerView. When I return to tab it initializes the recyclerView again. Here it doesn't know that it's been attached adapter before.

Comment: You can try to set a adapter in `oncreate` of fragment instead of `onresume`.

Comment: Could you please show it as code? I don't have idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code. Please take a look.

```
public class AllTabView extends Fragment {

Context ourContext;

RecyclerView mList;
AllAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
TextView mEmptyText;

long movedItem, draggedItem;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mDays = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_content, container, false);

    mList = (RecyclerView) v1.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mEmptyText = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    ourContext = getContext();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ourContext);
    mList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    getDays();
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    mList.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
    adapter = new AllAdapter(ourContext, mDays);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v1;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDays();
    if (mDays.size() == 0) {
        mList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void getDays() {
    DaysDatabase info = new DaysDatabase(ourContext);
    info.open();
    mDays.clear();
    mDays.addAll(info.getData());
    if (adapter != null)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    info.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Just add mDays=new ArrayList(); in above code in onCreatView so that it would not throw nullpointerexception on your ArrayList.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `ViewPager` to setup a Tab View.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I'm not wrong, ViewPager allows to swipe between tabs along with helping creating them. However, I don't need that feature because my tabs are on bottom of the screen. This is just design concepts I've chosen